# Check if generated xml file exist with setInterval

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

I need to generate an XML file and than check if the file exist. The XML file is large and it takes time to create. So I thought I use an interval and check if the file exist.

But i get only an **unlimited loop** although the file was created or sometimes a **404 (theXmlfile.xml)** in the browser console and everything stops.

```js
var tid;
  
jQuery("#cxml").click(function(){
 exeXml();  
 tid = setInterval(getAjax("theXmlfile.xml"),30000);  
 });
  
function exeXml(){ //The php file creates the XML file, this need some time
 var xmlhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();   
 xmlhttp.open("GET", "CreateXML.php", true);
 xmlhttp.send();   
 } 
  
 function getAjax(TheURL) {
   jQuery.ajax({
        url: TheURL,
        type:'HEAD',   
        error: function() {
         //error code
         //alert("File not successfully created");
   clearInterval(tid);
   tid = setInterval(getAjax("theXmlfile.xml"),30000);               
  },
        success: function(response) {
   // exists code    
   clearInterval(tid);
                 alert("File successfully created");
  }
   });
 }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`setInterval` takes a function as the first parameter, calling a function and passing a function is not the same thing.

```
tid = setInterval(function(){  // anonymous function passed to settimeout
    getAjax("theXmlfile.xml");
},30000);
```

```
tid = setInterval(getAjax("theXmlfile.xml"),30000); // calling a function
```

in your code above you are actually passing the return of getAjax to setTimeout which is undefined since it doesn't return anything.
This also means that you're not actually waiting before checking if your file is generating.